# Updating a map in java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have the following maps :

```
Map <String,String> m; // contains part details
Map <String,String> n; // contains part details
Map <String,String> o; // the new map that contains both m and n.
```

1. I want copy the values from `m` into o first.
2. I then want to loop though `n` and compare keys against `o`. If key from `n`, does not exist in `o` then put key/value it to `o`.

I tried the below, but the the the second step is not working (values are not copying)

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : m.entrySet())
{
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value =entry.getValue();

    o.put(key, value);
}


for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : n.entrySet())
{
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value =entry.getValue();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 : o.entrySet())
    {
        String key1 = entry.getKey();

         if(key1 != key)
        {
              o.put(key,value);
        }

     }      
}
```

Comment: that s really easy. you should try to do it yourself.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701960/union-of-two-or-more-hashmaps

Comment: The error is in `String key1 = entry.getKey();` it should be `String key1 = entry1.getKey();`.  In your code key1 is the same as key.  You should also use equals instead of != as the 2 key can be different object representing the same key.  But `addAll` will make your code better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Map#containsKey(). You can also iterate over a keyset, not over the entryset.

```
for (String key: n.keySet())
{
    if (!o.containsKey(key))
        o.put(key,n.get(key));
}
```

This should work.
I think the problem was you were using direct comparing of Strings, which is not sufficient in your case (almost never), use String#compareTo() method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use ready methods? You do not have to write all manually ;).

1) Method `putAll()` copies all values from one map to the second.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map)

2) Method `containsKey()` and only one loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to loop through o.

Just use o.containsKey() method

Answer (score 0):

In second inner for loop "String key1 = entry.getKey();" it should be "String key1 = entry1.getKey();"
mistaken between entry and entry1

Answer (score 0):

```
  o.putAll(m); // put all m into o
  n.keySet().removeAll(o.keySet()); // Remove all duplicates from n 
  o.putAll(n); // Now add all filtered n to o
```